# IdentityServer3 Should SubjectKey Be Populated for ClientCredential Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 in my web application.  Up to this point I had only used ResourceOwner flow.  I had my Token table set to not allow nulls on the SubjectKey field.

Now I am adding ClientCredential flow and getting an error saying that SubjectKey can not be null.

In my mind, it makes sense that SubjectKey would not be populated when using ClientCredential flow.  I think I should make that field in the table nullable, but I just want to verify that this is correct before making the change.

Comment: Are you confusing clients and users in your database?

Comment: No, that is what I am saying.  Up until now, I have been using ResourceOwner flow for users in my database, and SubjectKey was getting populated with their UserId.  But, now I need an internal only console application to access some of my same APIs and I am using ClientCredential flow.  In this scenario, no SubjectKey is populated on the token (which makes sense to me), but I setup my database to require a SubjectKey.  I was going to change the table to make SubjectKey nullable, but I wanted to verify that this is expected behavior before doing so.

Comment: You should store client credentials as a separate "thing" in your DB.